# Optional Dependencies in Odoo 14 CE

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Is there any way to make optional dependencies in Odoo 14 CE?

I know that there is a dependency attribute in the manifest file that we need to specify, and yes, I have been using it to the best of my abilities.

However, I sometimes need to write some code for only when a module is installed, but even if it isn't then the rest of the code should function properly without such module.

For example, My custom module will add a field in `sale` and `account`, but if this database has `purchase` installed then it will also add a field in it too. Pretty simple concept, right, but I can't find a way to do it in a single module.

Comment: Interesting question! Sometimes we use the concept of something like a base module (base functionalities and if possible as less dependencies to other modules as possible) and integrating modules for odoo apps like sale, account and so on. On those integrating modules you can set the right dependencies and `auto_install` to `True` which will Odoo tell, to install the module if every dependency is already installed.

Comment: @CZoellner so that must be a different module for that matter. I would love to have just a single module.

Comment: Yes, that's why i didn't write my idea as answer but as comment ;-)

Comment: @holydragon You can do it using hooks and custom fields.

Comment: @Kenly Can you elaborate? I have never used hooks before, or maybe I have used it but I don't know but hooks are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [post_init_hook](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/module.html), which is executed right after the module’s installation, to check if the `purchase` (`purchase.order` is in registry) module is installed and add the custom field. You can even load an XML file to add the custom field by inheritance using the [convert_xml_import](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/tools/convert.py#L732) function which convert and import XML files.

It is similar to adding the field manually to the corresponding model and view.

When you uninstall the module, the custom field will not be deleted and to do so, you will need to use the `uninstall_hook`, you will also need to delete the view manually because of the following user error:

> User Error
> Cannot rename/delete fields that are still present in views
> Fields: purchase.order.x_reference
> View: purchase.order.form

First set the `post_init_hook`, `uninstall_hook` functions inside the `__manifest__.py` file:

```
'post_init_hook': '_module_post_init',
'uninstall_hook': '_module_uninstall_hook',
```

Then define those functions inside the `__init__.py` file:

```py
import os
from odoo import fields, api, SUPERUSER_ID, tools, modules
from odoo.tools.misc import file_open


def _module_uninstall_hook(cr, registry):
    if 'purchase.order' in registry:
        env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
        env.ref('stackoverflow_14.purchase_order_form').unlink()
        env['ir.model.fields'].search([('name', '=', 'x_reference')]).unlink()


def _module_post_init(cr, registry):
    if 'purchase.order' in registry:
        env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
        mp = env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', 'purchase.order')], limit=1)
        mp.write({'field_id': [(0, 0, {
            'name': 'x_reference',
            'field_description': "Reference",
            'ttype': 'char',
        })]})
        pathname = os.path.join(modules.get_module_path('stackoverflow_14'), 'views', 'purchase_order.xml')
        with file_open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
            tools.convert.convert_xml_import(cr, 'stackoverflow_14', fp)
```

The `purchase_order.xml` file defined inside `views` use the view inheritance to add the custom field to the `purchase_order_form` form view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="purchase_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="partner_ref" position="after">
                    <field name="x_reference"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Very nice concept and implementation!