# Odoo Python Function TypeError: EventBooth.check_app_installed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, function, odoo, self

What is necessary to make this peace of code working?
I always get the error "Function TypeError: EventBooth.check_app_installed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". Meanwhile I tried a lot of different approaches, but nothing worked.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class EventBooth(models.Model):
    _name = 'event.booth'

    @api.model
    def check_app_installed(self):
        # Check if the 'event' app is installed
        event_app_installed = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'event'), ('state', '=', 'installed')])
        
        return event_app_installed

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        app_installed = self.check_app_installed()
        if not app_installed:
            # Install the 'event' app if it is not installed
            event_app = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'event')])
            event_app.button_immediate_install()

        # Continue with the creation of the record
        return super(EventBooth, self).create(vals)

    if check_app_installed():
        _inherit = 'event.booth'
        price = fields.Float(string='Price')
```

Comment: The error raised beacuse of this line ```if check_app_installed():``` in your code. what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure Odoo loads the `event` module before yours, add it to the manifest [depends](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/module.html?highlight=manifest#manifest) entry.

From Odoo documentation:

> Odoo modules which must be loaded before this one, either because this module uses features they create or because it alters resources they define.
> When a module is installed, all of its dependencies are installed before it. Likewise dependencies are loaded before a module is loaded.

To make optional dependencies, check  [Optional Dependencies in Odoo 14 CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534848/optional-dependencies-in-odoo-14-ce/69588788#69588788) answer